# Polymorphic many-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following examples differ only in the **Book** and **Movie** models.

Example 1: `Book has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable`

Example 2: `Book has_many :taggings, :through => :taggable`

What does this difference mean?

---

**[Example 1](http://www.brentmc79.com/posts/polymorphic-many-to-many-associations-in-rails):**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :books, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Book"
  has_many :movies, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Movie"
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

**[Example 2:](http://blog.dharanasoft.com/2011/09/06/polymorphic-many-to-many-associations-in-rails/)**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :through => :taggable
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :through => :taggable
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :books, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Book"
  has_many :movies, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Movie"
end


class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the 2nd example works?    I don't have an rails environment in windows. 
For my understanding about your question,

case1.

```
has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
```

here the "taggable" is not an exact Model name, it's just an alias. (there's no Taggable class)

case2.

```
has_many :taggings, :through => :taggable
```

here the "taggable" must be an real (exsting) model, I mean there must be an Taggable class somewhere.

refer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Thanks. I'm also not sure if the second case works. I found these code examples in blog posts. There's a comment in the second post about changing ":through => :taggable" to ":as => :taggable". You're probably right that it won't work unless there is a Taggable class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the examples worked .. and taggable was a real model .. which as Siwei suggests probably doesn't actually work ...

```
:as defines a polymorphic association
```

and

```
:through says that
   if A has many B's
   and B has many C's
   then A has many C's through B
```